How can I import the ESM-only module in my NestJS CommonJS project?
I'm trying to use the strip-ansi package in my NestJS project, which uses ES style imports but compiles to JavaScript using CommonJS.
Here is how I use imports in my files:
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import stringify from 'safe-stable-stringify';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { LogEntry } from './log-entry.entity';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';

My tsconfig.json:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictBindCallApply": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist", "Default", "test", "**/*spec.ts"]
}

The problem I'm facing is when I import the strip-ansi package as instructed in their documentation: import stripAnsi from 'strip-ansi';
I get this error:
/home/user/project_prod/project-backend/dist/src/logging/logger.service.js:21
const strip_ansi_1 = require("strip-ansi");
                     ^
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /home/user/project_prod/project-backend/node_modules/strip-ansi/index.js from /home/user/project_prod/project-backend/dist/src/logging/logger.service.js not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in /home/user/project_prod/project-backend/dist/src/logging/logger.service.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/user/project_prod/project-backend/dist/src/logging/logger.service.js:21:22)

I don't want to change my import style or anything like that.
Things that I've tried are:
1.
let stripAnsi: (input: string) => string;

import('strip-ansi').then((module) => {
  stripAnsi = module.default;
});

But then I'm facing this error:
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /home/user/project_prod/project-backend/node_modules/strip-ansi/index.js from /home/user/project_prod/project-backend/dist/src/logging/logger.service.js not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in /home/user/project_prod/project-backend/dist/src/logging/logger.service.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
    at /home/user/project_prod/project-backend/dist/src/logging/logger.service.js:22:30

2.
Also, I've tried: import stripAnsi = require('strip-ansi')
But then when I use the stripAnsi method I get:
"This expression is not callable.
Type 'typeof import("/home/user/project_prod/project-backend/node_modules/strip-ansi/index")' has no call signatures. ts(2349)

For context, Here is how node_modules/strip-ansi/index.d.ts looks like:
export default function stripAnsi(string: string): string;

One fix for this is dynamic importing, but I don't want to use it because the part where I would use this would be called a lot in my project, and I think that it could slow down my app significantly if every time this code is executing, importing of a package will be happening.
How can I fix this without using dynamic importing?

Cant reproduce. When you import stripAnsi from "strip-ansi"; you get an error?

Yes, I get this error: "...Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module...".
I figured that I'm getting this error because my NestJS project, which is running TypeScript and ES style imports is being compiled into JavaScript with commonJS style imports, which is a usual and conventional setup, because there are still older npm packages which still run on commonJS and this is needed for backward compatibility. This is default configuration btw.

Yea i get that but i copy paste your code and i don't get an error while transpailing. You get it when you run it?

Yeah, I get this error when I run my NestJS app with:
"npm start:debug", which actually runs "nest start --debug --watch".
As far as I know it compiles the code in real-time, just like it would if I ran "nest build".
